# How to implement content-based health check for GKE ingress

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress, kubernetes-health-check

I want to implement a [content-based health check](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/health-check-concepts#content-based_health_checks) for my GKE ingress. These kinds of health checks are usually specified in the BackendConfig CRD. My current BackendConfig looks like this:

```
apiVersion: cloud.google.com/v1
kind: BackendConfig
metadata:
  name: XXX-hc-config
spec:
  healthCheck:
    checkIntervalSec: 15
    timeoutSec: 5
    port: 8080
    type: HTTP
    requestPath: /healthz
```

As seen in the link above, Google DOES support content-based health checks. But I cannot see, how to configure this. I expected something like:

```
healthCheck:
    checkIntervalSec: 15
    timeoutSec: 5
    port: 8080
    type: HTTP
    requestPath: /healthz
    response: "OK" <--- THIS IS NEW
```

but I cannot find anything about it. Not even in the CRD source code. Did anyone ever do this successfully? How?

In the GCP console you can set it like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the console, you can try this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/health-checks#optional-flags-hc-protocol-http) on how to create a health check with a response string for HTTP, HTTPS, and HTTP/2 health checks.

```
gcloud compute health-checks create HTTP\_PROTOCOL hc-http-port-80 

COMMON\_FLAGS 

PORT\_SPECIFICATION 

--host=HOST 

--proxy-header=PROXY\_HEADER 

--request-path=REQUEST\_PATH 

--response=RESPONSE
```

For SSL and TCP health checks you can use this [guidance](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/health-checks#optional-flags-hc-protocol-ssl-tcp).

```
gcloud compute health-checks create tcp hc-tcp-3268 

COMMON\_FLAGS 

PORT\_SPECIFICATION 

--proxy-header=PROXY\_HEADER 

--request=REQUEST\_STRING 

--response=RESPONSE\_STRING
```

Upon checking the [custom health check configuration](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/ingress-configuration#direct_health) it seems that there is no option in yaml to place a response string.

Comment: Thanks for the research, but I already saw all that. I need a way to put this into yaml, that's my problem...